# How to convert R,G,B,W signal to 1 wire in LED strips

Tags: led-strip, led-driver

I found this [RGBW controller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001489996035.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.3a513c00pWfi26&mp=1) which I really like aesthetically , the only problem is that this only works for LED strips that are 12V with separate R, G, B, W, data lines and the strips I have are the WS2812B which only have 1 data line and are 5V.

The solution I came up with is to place a microcontroller say an ESP with WiFi or an Arduino with WiFi which opens up me controlling the strips via WiFi at the same time with that wall mounted controller.

I already understood how WS2812B strips work with the help of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249162/how-does-an-addressable-led-in-a-strip-work). Not to mention the vast libraries available for the chip. My only problem now I don't know what kind of signal/protocol the R,G,B,W data lines are spitting out.

- Are they analog / digital?
- Where can I read more on it? I'm having a hard time finding the datasheets (probably just my bad googling skills.)

Comment: See the datasheet http://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2801.pdf  page 12 / 15.  8 bit for red, 8 bit for green, 8 bit for blue.

Comment: @nick_n_a im sorry im having trouble veiwing the link, looks like its broken

Comment: link is valid ... .maybe it is blocked in your part of the world

Comment: @nick_n_a I just went ahead and google WS2801 datasheet, the typical application [image](https://ibb.co/Z2zn6Dh) does not seem to have separate data lines for each color. The contoller expects a leds strip that accepts 1 dataline for each color [like this](https://ibb.co/pdjRRyt). If its just like the WS2812 but instead 8bits on separate line are they simultaneus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

All RGB/RGBWW/CCT/etc constant voltage strips are wired the same: common anode (ie, "Plus") and one cathode per color. The controller connects each cathode to ground with a FET to light the corresponding LEDs.

Brightness is usually modulated with PWM. It would be very surprising to find a switching constant current inside these controllers.

So, if you want to use this to control WS2812B:

First, measure the voltage between the controller's ground and the outputs while playing with the controls, or just open it to check the outputs are just simple FETs to ground.

Then:

[image]

The FET on the left is inside the controller. You add the components on the right to filter the PWM waveform into a voltage that can be acquired by the ADC. You can also remove the capacitor and use one timer in capture mode per channel to acquire the duty cycle, but that's a bit more software.

Then you need to write code to translate these values into WS2812B protocol and drive them from your micro.

Note WS2813B are quite inefficient and expensive compared to standard 24V RGB strips, so using WS2812B is only justified if you need to address each LED individually.

You could also check if the controller can be powered by 5V instead of 12V. If it works, then you can use the same 5V power supply for everything.

**EDIT**

Note "MicroVCC" on the schematic is the VCC of your Micro, ie the max voltage the ADC input will tolerate. If the micro runs on 3V3 through a 5V LDO from a 5V supply, then what I mean on the schematic is of course 3V3.

Also the output is inverted. LEDs OFF will be max ADC value, LEDs ON (thus MOSFET ON) will be ADC close to zero.

Comment: I do like the WS2812B that i have, although its not all the time i need its individually addressable feature but great to have nonetheless.

Comment: Hopefully its an open collector type(or similar) then i would not have to worry about level shifting. So if i understand correctly, the signal on each color are just PWM signals? not some 8 bit protocols? Atleast that would be much easier to read

Comment: It it's designed to drive standard LED strips which are just LEDs and resistors, these have no brains so they can't decode any protocol. Since PWM is the cheapest option, this is likely what you'll get. Linear current sink would overheat, and switching current sink would be more $$$.

Comment: Great ! Thank you sir, cant wait for the wall mount controller to arrive so i can play with it a bit.

Comment: And... where is the RGBanalog-to-1digital converter?

Comment: @nick_n_a The question was actually about misunderstanding how standard LED strips work. I'm sure OP can write code to read an ADC value and he knows how to drive WS2182B.

Comment: LED cathodes are the "Minus". Not the "Plus". The opposite as for batteries.

Comment: damn, fixed, thanks